# How can I hide app's name in Android when using a theme with no action bar?

Tags: java, android, material-design

The app_name is appearing in the top left corner for some reason. Why? See here:

[emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRYo5.jpg)

My app runs in full screen and hides UI elements, like the action bar. The only two components in the app are a constraint view and the center textView that shows the word "voluble."

The only thing I could imagine might be causing this is the app's parent theme, which is Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar. But I still can't find how to prevent this from happening or why it's happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I was using this function to hide the UI elements:

```
    public void fullScreenCall() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

which I call from:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    fullScreenCall();
}
```

Adding this to the fullScreenCall function's uiOptions fixes it for some reason:

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
```

Final working code:

```
    public void fullScreenCall() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```